# Converting the neighbours MAC address to IP address ns-3

Tags: network-programming, ns-3

I need the list or MAC-IP addresses of all the first hop neighbors of a wireless node so that I can find the IP from the MAC address, where can I get that in ns-3, I need to do that at the network layer (Ipv4-protocol) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this function must be implemented by yourself or using existing protocol, like in real network you need hello messages to get first hop neighbors. The simplest way to do that is to broadcast HELLO messages and keep track of those you hear.
This is already implemented in OLSR and AODV protocols and it is not hard to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet for accessing an IP address of a node at any layer:

```
ns3::Ptr ipv4 = n->GetObject (); 

Ipv4Address ip = ipv4->GetAddress( 1, 0 ).GetLocal();
```

Here 1 is the interface index for its assigned IP address. The interface index 0 is a loopback interface which gives 127.0.0.1 address.

A similar answer can be found [here](https://malleshamdasari.wordpress.com/blog-posts/page/3/).